# Python 3.7, EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python, python-3.7

I can't run my code, I'm using `atom.io`, `python 3.7`. Here is my code:

```
num1 = input("enter a number: ")
num2 = input("enter another number: ")
result = int(num1) + int(num2)
print(result)
```

It keeps saying like this:

```
enter a number: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\icebergnes\Desktop\CODE\Calculator Basic.py", line 2, in <module>
    num1 = input("enter a number: ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: Your sure you're using 3.7?

Comment: Is this all your code?

Comment: It is because you are using Atom and it does not support `input()`, you should try with a regular terminal. See https://discuss.atom.io/t/is-there-a-way-to-run-code-requiring-user-input-eoferror-eof-when-reading-a-line/32482

Comment: you might passing non int strings in input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An EOFError is raised when a built-in function like input() or raw_input() do not read any data before encountering the end of their input stream.

Try using the try except to see if it works.

```
try:
   #your code

except EOFError as e:
   print(e)
```

Comment: Also try on some other editor - IDLE or VScode. Atom does have some issues.

Comment: within your except you should have added the solution for OP to deal with this type of error. Raise the error and try to fix it directly. So.. in the except there is an try/except with a pass in the second except to return to the first try/except to go to the else or finally to fix or skip. Right now you just give info how to debug. Then use `if type(None) ==type (num1):`..etc.