# EOFError when deploying google cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have the following `main.py` file, that works when created through the website.
When I try to do the same by the gcloud, I receive an error about `EOFError: EOF when reading a line; Error ID: c84b3231`

The command I'm using is `gcloud functions deploy xpto --project=project_xpto --entry-point=xpto --runtime=python39 --source=xpto --trigger-http --vpc-connector=redis --allow-unauthenticated`
I already tried adding `beta` to the command, and nothing happens.

My `main.py` file is that below

```
import json
import logging
from datetime import date
from http import HTTPStatus
from flask import Request
import service

setup_logger()
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def xpto(request: Request, token: str):
    LOGGER.info(f"{request.method} accepted.")

    id = get_id(token)

    res_xpto = get_xpto(id=id)

    return make_response(
        json.dumps(res_xpto, default=lambda t: str(t) if isinstance(t, date) else t),
        http_code=HTTPStatus.OK,
        headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    )
```

Curiously, while trying to get it to work, I created a new CF with only the code below, and the same gcloud command works

```
def hello_world(request):
    return "Hello World"
```

EDIT:

`requirements.txt`

```
--extra-index-url {URL}

cachetools==4.2.2; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
certifi==2021.5.30; python_version >= "3.9" and python_full_version < "3.0.0" and python_version < "4.0" or python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0" and python_full_version >= "3.6.0"
cffi==1.14.6; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
charset-normalizer==2.0.4; python_full_version >= "3.6.0" and python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
click==7.1.2; (python_version >= "2.7" and python_full_version < "3.0.0") or (python_full_version >= "3.5.0")
cloudevents==1.2.0
cryptography==3.4.8; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
deprecation==2.1.0
flask==1.1.2; (python_version >= "2.7" and python_full_version < "3.0.0") or (python_full_version >= "3.5.0")
functions-framework==2.1.0; python_version >= "3.5" and python_version < "4"
google-api-core==2.0.1; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
google-auth==2.0.2; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
google-cloud-secret-manager==2.7.0; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
googleapis-common-protos==1.53.0; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
greenlet==1.1.1; python_version >= "3" and python_full_version < "3.0.0" or python_full_version >= "3.6.0" and python_version >= "3"
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.12.3; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
grpcio==1.39.0; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
gunicorn==20.0.4; python_version >= "3.4"
idna==3.2; python_version >= "3.9" and python_full_version < "3.0.0" and python_version < "4.0" or python_full_version >= "3.6.0" and python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
itsdangerous==1.1.0; (python_version >= "2.7" and python_full_version < "3.0.0") or (python_full_version >= "3.4.0")
jinja2==2.11.2; (python_version >= "2.7" and python_full_version < "3.0.0") or (python_full_version >= "3.5.0")
libcst==0.3.20; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
markupsafe==1.1.1; (python_version >= "2.7" and python_full_version < "3.0.0") or (python_full_version >= "3.4.0")
mypy-extensions==0.4.3; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
mysqlclient==2.0.3; python_version >= "3.5"
packaging==21.0; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
pathtools==0.1.2
phpserialize==1.3
proto-plus==1.19.0; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
protobuf==3.17.3; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
pyasn1==0.4.8; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
pycparser==2.20; python_version >= "3.9" and python_full_version < "3.0.0" and python_version < "4.0" or python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0" and python_full_version >= "3.4.0"
pydantic==1.8.2; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0" and python_full_version >= "3.6.1"
pyjwt==2.1.0; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
pyparsing==2.4.7; python_version >= "3.6" and python_full_version < "3.0.0" or python_full_version >= "3.3.0" and python_version >= "3.6"
pyyaml==5.4.1; python_version >= "3.9" and python_full_version < "3.0.0" and python_version < "4.0" or python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0" and python_full_version >= "3.6.0"
requests==2.26.0; (python_version >= "2.7" and python_full_version < "3.0.0") or (python_full_version >= "3.6.0")
rsa==4.7.2; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4"
six==1.16.0; python_version >= "3.9" and python_full_version < "3.0.0" and python_version < "4.0" or python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0" and python_full_version >= "3.3.0"
sqlalchemy==1.4.22; (python_version >= "2.7" and python_full_version < "3.0.0") or (python_full_version >= "3.6.0")
tenacity==7.0.0
typing-extensions==3.10.0.2; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0" and python_full_version >= "3.6.1"
typing-inspect==0.7.1; python_version >= "3.9" and python_version < "4.0"
urllib3==1.26.6; python_version >= "3.9" and python_full_version < "3.0.0" and python_version < "4.0" or python_full_version >= "3.6.0" and python_version < "4" and python_version >= "3.9"
watchdog==1.0.2; python_version >= "3.6"
werkzeug==1.0.1; (python_version >= "2.7" and python_full_version < "3.0.0") or (python_full_version >= "3.5.0")
```

Comment: Hi, can you please provide us your requirement.txt file? so that we can try to reproduce the error

Comment: edited, please take a look

Comment: I have found a few links which deal with similar error message, and in this it is suggested to use try-except block, can you see if this helps you? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/handling-eoferror-exception-in-python/ ,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56734005/pyhton-3-7-eoferror-eof-when-reading-a-line, https://try2explore.com/questions/10437412

Answer (score 0):

Probably its set to CRLF line breaks, you can use `dos2unix` to convert the script to Unix format

Comment: nope, I've changed everything to LF only, got the same error